# jquery-migrate error on wordpress deployment

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having an error after I deploy my WordPress from localhost to online, I think its on the jQuery migrate file.

[image: Browser console screenshot]

Error:

> TypeError: jQuery.attrHooks is undefined.

It's my first time using WordPress and deploying it online, by the way. This error doesn't appear when I'm still developing it locally. I'm not really sure if this is a problem on WordPress or on jQuery.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Please only provide the text of the errors... please do not post screenshots of the error message.

Comment: How do you load you jquery library? Does it get loaded at all? Also give the url your deployed wp page, it's easier to help you then than just seeing a screenshot :)

Comment: Ok @Sparky, I just thought it will be more helpful if I add it on. anyway the error was TypeError: jQuery.attrHooks is undefined.

Comment: yes its loaded @BadrHari http://levelup.sic.edu.ph/

Comment: Does this error happen in admin page or front-end? If front, are you aware WP sets the jQuery to the noConflict() mode?

Comment: Yes @BadrHari its also having that error on admin page.. I am not aware of that noConflict() too on wp.. ill research on that too

Comment: jquery-migrate-1.2.1 requires jQuery 1.9+, you're using much older version of jquery. Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Thank you so much @BadrHari though im still gettings some errors in my console, but this time my ubermenu plugin is now working. Your really good person sir ! have a nice day! ill try to figure this one out and try to remove this errors.